# Android INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION while starting the app

Tags: android

I'm new to android development and this is my first try out. when try to run the template project created by android studio I'm seeing below error.

```
Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION: Failed parse during installPackageLI: Failed to read manifest from /data/app/vmdl2093545946.tmp/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk: null
```

below is the *AndroidManifest.xml* file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.customtab">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and here is the *activity_main.xml* file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello Android !"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

wondering what I'm missing here.

Comment: 1._clean project. 2_rebuild  project

Comment: Just did, but no luck!

Comment: Downgraded the targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion to 28 from 30 and working fine.

Comment: Please share more code or Can send your code to my email?

Comment: @JavadDehban now working fine after changing the targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion.

Comment: it's very good.

Answer (score 3):

I have also just experienced this error when trying to run my app targeting the API30 on an Android API 30 Emulator. Clean and rebuid did not help and downgrading the target API back to 29 was not an option for me, because I needed to test the app targeting API 30. Turned out that the cause was Instant Run feature enabled in Android Studio.

Solution was found [here](https://www.programmersought.com/article/46438395220/).

Answer (score 0):

try to turn off the **instant run** from Settings>Build Execution, Deployment > Instant Run.
then Rebuild Your project and run it.